# Bootstrap 2.3.1 and JQuery 2.0.2 not working in IE 8 for MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have updated Jquery 2.0.2 after that my MVC4 site not working IE8. It is working fine in IE 10 and chrome and FF.

I have included below code in _layout.cshtml. Still it not working

```
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

What will be the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Source: www.jquery.com

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Comment: Or see the browser support page http://jquery.com/browser-support/. Still, useful info.